# Creating password protected folders inside password protected samba share

Tags: linux, centos, samba, administration

I have already created a password protected samba share which is working fine, but my organizations requirement is as follows:

- Separate password protected directories for each department
- Inside every department another password protected folder each employee

It will look like this

- Department name folder (password protected)

  - EMP 1 (password protected)
  - EMP 2 (password protected)

Any idea how to create a configuration like this using SAMBA? I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: Modern security requirements very rarely require simple password protection these days because that implies shared passwords which are bad practice. More commonly the requirement is for user access control. A user might need to input their password to authenticate, but access to the directory is managed by controlling which user can access what.

Comment: Could you confirm that you specifically are looking to put an anonymous password on the directory and not user access control.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more on what you are looking for? Sorry i am new to this

Comment: What's the purpose of having the employee shares inside the department share?  It would be simpler to have one or more group shares for each department (with individual employees being members of the appropriate department groups) and individual employee shares in their own home directory.  If the employee shares are under a department group directory then, without very careful permissions management, whoever has write access to the group share directory effectively has full access to the employee directories beneath it.

Comment: Got it. Someone else told to make different folders for each employee. Suppose each department has 2 employees and there are 2 departments. ill be making 4 different password protected share. In this case they can only access their folders. Obviously this would take a lot more time than making folders for department.

Comment: Actually, no.  Personal shares for each user's home directory are basically automatic, with just a `[homes]` section in smb.conf.   Group shares for each department would each need to be set up with their own section in smb.conf or an `include` file (with `create mode = 0664`, `directory mode 2755` and a `valid users` list and `force user`/`force group` settings - and, yes, this can be automated with good planning and a good script) - once they're set up, group members can access the share using their own username & password.